# Combining '&' and 'currency_code' in PHP

Tags: php, ampersand

I have a strange problem with PHP. Basically I was trying to do this:

```
$string = '&currency_code';
```

when I try to echo $string the output is:

```
¤cy_code
```

Has anyone encountered this? How can we get around this?

Comment: Interesting ... are you sure you're using single quotes and not double quotes?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Maybe include more code?

Comment: i tried both to no avail.

Comment: @Matchu that's basically the code needed to reproduce. I am using PHP version 5.4.5

Comment: `$string = '&amp;currency_code';`

Comment: @u_milder that works! But why do we have to resort to this? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&curren` is an HTML entity; browsers will render it as the ¤ symbol.

Always run `htmlspecialchars` on any non-HTML text you want to output to avoid unexpected behavior like this.

```
$string = "&currency_code";
$escaped_string = htmlspecialchars($string);
echo $escaped_string; // outputs the HTML "&amp;currency_code", which
                      // appears to the user as "&currency_code".
```

Comment: htmlspecialchars - that's it! It's been a while since I've been using PHP on a daily basis. Thanks.